# Views 3.8: Show taxonomy hierarchy in three columns (grandparent, parent, child)

Tags: 7, views, taxonomy-terms

I have a taxonomy with a three-level hierarchy, and would like to display the three levels in a views table, but separately. I'd also like to have an exposed filter using that taxonomy and let my users pick the term.

Here's what I've done:

1. Added the contextual filter **Has taxonomy term id depth modifier**
2. Added the relationship **Content: Taxonomy terms on node** with an identifier "term"
3. Added the relationship **Taxonomy term: Parent term** with an identifier "Parent" and set its relationship as "term"
4. Added the contextual filter **Taxonomy term: Parent term** and selected the "Parent" relationship
5. Added the taxonomy term field

At this point I can display the hierarchy in a single column and can choose between the lowest level child or all three (e.g. Grandparent > Parent > Child). However, I want to be able to display the grandparent, parent and child in separate columns.

Is this possible? I was hoping to maybe add the field three times and pick the hierarchy level, but I don't see how to do that.

Answer (score 3):

If you've only 3 level of hierarchy then you can create a view as below:

[image]

Above view should give the output as below:
[image]

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

First you need to generate the desired **3 column table** without *Views*. Then you can use [*Views*](https://www.drupal.org/project/views)'s to load the desired *nodes* with [contextual filters](https://www.drupal.org/search/site/contextual%20filters). Possible to do following the stes below, but there is many different ways to do.

1. Create a **module** with the [mymodule_taxonomy_get_tree_nested()](https://api.drupal.org/comment/60558#comment-60558) **function**
2. **call** it from the [template.php](http://www.drupalcontrib.org/api/drupal/drupal%21themes%21seven%21template.php/7)
3. figure out what and how do you want to **display**
4. you can [**render** Arrays with Drupal](https://www.drupal.org/docs/7/api/render-arrays/render-arrays-overview) after some *"makeup"*
5. load the desired content with **View**, using the *Content: Has taxonomy term ID* **contextual filter**

Answer (score 0):

Also. I believe, you can use ready-done module for it https://www.drupal.org/project/views_tree.